# Storing a attribute with JSON value in CosmosDB using Entity Framework Core 3

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.1, ef-model-first

I using EF Core Cosmos Provider in my API to consume my CosmosDB. Inside my container items in cosmos , I want a Attribute to store JSON value and also should be mapped to my models classes in EF core. Items in my cosmos container looks like this:

[image: Sample items for reference]

As you can see that the fields inside **the "Parameters" attribute are dynamic, how can I map this to a model class in EF core?**

For now I have implemented it using __jObject shadow property that allows us to store values as JObject's in our container, but on the official documentation site for __jObject, the have said and I quote :

"The "__jObject" property is part of the EF Core infrastructure and should only be used as a last resort as it is likely to have different behavior in future releases."

If you have any insights on what kind of changes I should expect in **__jObject behavior in future releases**, it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use the image but just copy your code and paste it.